# R rollapply throws errors in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table and want to execute a `rollapply` to calculate a rolling average for a particular group.  I have:

```
tt <- data.table(tt, key = c("dt", "id"))

dt      id  val
1/1/14  a    NA
1/2/14  a    3
1/3/14  a    2
1/4/14  a    5
...      
2/1/14  a    NA
1/1/14  b    NA
1/2/14  b    9
1/3/14  b   10
...
2/1/14  b   12
```

I want to do a three-day rolling average for each `id` whenever there is valid data.  I tried:

```
tt[, test := rollapply(val, FUN = mean, 
  width = 3, na.rm = TRUE), by = list(id))
```

This gives some odd warnings and then NaNs.  Have I done something wrong?

Comment: This `tt[, list(test=rollapply(val, FUN=mean, width=3, na.rm=TRUE)), by=id]` didn't give warnings on an example dataset I tried.

Comment: `dt` is not an R Date field, so it is probably sorted as alpha and not the way you are expecting.

Comment: Use appropriate `fill` or `partial` arguments of `rollapply` so that the output of `rollapply` is the same length as the input.

Comment: I'm going to add this as an answer and shut down the Q, but this was perfect. I didn't realize I needed to add that `partial` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved within the `rollapply` function itself.  I needed to add the `partial` argument.  This worked great:

```
tt[, test := rollapply(val, FUN = mean, width = 3, na.rm = TRUE, 
   partial = TRUE), by = list(id)]
```